# Resize Table, elsarticle document class

Tags: tables, elsarticle, resize

On my previous question [creating tables with multi row and column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/449837/creating-tables-with-multi-row-and-column) @zarko provide answer which not fulfill my requirements. i used it as base form new code for my table, but my effort doesnt gives what i expect. the code below gives:

[image]

```
documentclass[final,1p,times,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{siunitx}%
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
\caption{Augmented Dickey Fuller and KPSS Test Statistics for (Transformed) Sectoral Indices (y)}
\label{tab:statistics}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
%\sisetup{input-symbols={( - )},
         %table-space-text-pre={(},
         %table-space-text-post ={)},
         %}  
                    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                            l
                       *{2}{S[table-format=-1.3]
                            @{\hspace{-1.2em}}
                             S[table-format=1.2]}
                                }
    \toprule
\thead[l]{\\Banking-industry specific variables}
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Levin, Lin and\\ Chu (LLC)}}
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{ADF-Fisher\\ chi-square}}    \\
     \cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(r){2-3}\cmidrule{4-5}

Log of Loans-to-Assets  &-2.14  & &151.23& \\
&\textit{(0.05)}& &\textit{(0.02)}\\

Log of Credit quality &-0.486 & & 144.11& \\
&\textit{(0.04)}& &\textit{(0.01)}\\

Log of Diversification &2.441 & &112.23& \\
&\textit{(0.02)}& &\textit{(0.04)}\\

Log of Return on Assets &-3.235 & & 1.140& \\
&\textit{(0.01)}& &\textit{(0.03)}\\   

        \midrule
\textbf{Macroeconomic variables}
                        &       &           &
                                    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Fisher-ADF}}  \\
    \midrule
Real GDP growth         &       &           & -1.66     &   \\
&&&\textit{(0.048)}\\ 
$\Delta$ infl (inflation) &       &           & -4.62     &    \\
&&&\textit{(0.145)}\\ 

$\Delta$ Ur (unemployment rate)   &       &           & -1.45     &    \\
&&&\textit{(0.014)}\\ 

Exchange rate           &       &           & -0.76     &   \\
&&&\textit{(0.042)}\\ 

    \midrule
\textbf{Household-level indicators}
                        &       &           &
                                    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Fisher-ADF}}  \\
    \midrule
Income                  &       &           & 1.30      &          \\
&&&\textit{(0.001)}\\ 

Family size             &       &           & -1.07     &         \\
&&&\textit{(0.007)}\\ 

Age                     &       &           & -3.02     &        \\
&&&\textit{(0.002)}\\ 

Education               &       &           & -1.91     &       \\
&&&\textit{(0.000)}\\ 

    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
        \end{adjustbox}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you should tel us, what is the problem :-). as far as i can see, you should removed not used columns ... also it would be nice from you, if you mentioned, that code in your question is based on mine answer

Comment: i'm sorry  ur right, i have mentioned ur name in the question, acutually i want to reduce the size of the hall table

Comment: avtualy you should ad link to your previous, not mentioned my name as such. since i didn't suggest such a solution but something else. you try to redesign my solution and you stuck in this. i will take liberty and edit your question and add mentioned information.

Answer (score 2):

Some comments and observations:

- There's no need for `adjustbox`.
- Keep the column structure simple: One column for labels, two columns for data.
- Using the `siunitx` package and its `S` column type may be a bit of overkill for the current typesetting needs. All that's needed is the `dcolumn` package.
- Less visual drama, please -- there's no need for **bold-facing** and **italics**, really.

[image]

```
\documentclass[1p,times]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Augmented Dickey Fuller and KPSS Test Statistics for (Transformed) Sectoral Indices (y)}
\label{tab:statistics}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % make LaTeX do all the work

\smallskip
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l d{2.3} d{3.3} }
\toprule
Banking-industry specific variables
    &  \mc{Levin, Lin and Chu (LLC)}
    &  \mc{ADF-Fisher chi-square}    \\
\cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{2-2}\cmidrule{3-3}

Log of Loans-to-Assets  &-2.14  & 151.23 \\
                        &(0.05) & (0.02) \\
Log of Credit quality   &-0.486 & 144.11 \\
                        &(0.04) & (0.01) \\
Log of Diversification  &2.441  & 112.23 \\
                        &(0.02) & (0.04) \\
Log of Return on Assets &-3.235 & 1.140  \\
                        &(0.01) & (0.03) \\   
\addlinespace
Macroeconomic variables &&\mc{Fisher-ADF}  \\
\cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{3-3}
Real GDP growth           && -1.66   \\
                          && (0.048) \\ 
$\Delta$ infl (inflation) && -4.62   \\
                          && (0.145)\\ 
$\Delta$ Ur (unemployment rate) && -1.45  \\
                          && (0.014) \\ 
Exchange rate             && -0.76   \\
                          && (0.042) \\ 
\addlinespace
Household-level indicators&& \mc{Fisher-ADF}  \\
\cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{3-3}
Income                    && 1.30    \\
                          && (0.001) \\ 
Family size               &&-1.07    \\
                          && (0.007) \\ 
Age                       &&-3.02    \\
                          && (0.002) \\ 
Education                 &&-1.91    \\
                          && (0.000) \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```